# Keyboard-Shortcut to move windows around on multiscreen setup

Tags: windows, linux, macos, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automagically move windows between monitors with one keystroke?](https://superuser.com/questions/331313/how-to-automagically-move-windows-between-monitors-with-one-keystroke)

I am looking for a way to move windows around on a multi-screen (usually dual screen) setup. So with a keyboard shortcut (or mouse click) I would like to send a window to another monitor.

I am using this functionality a lot when I give presentations. I'll look up something on my main screen and then send the window to the screen or beamer where others can see it. It's also useful when working or when I want to send a screen from my computer to the TV screen that is hooked up to the computer.

How can I set that up, for the three major operating systems Windows, OS X and Linux?

Comment: the mac solution can be found at http://macfidelity.de/2009/03/31/mac-programm-auf-zweitem-monitor-betreiben/index.html. I can not post it here yet since my reputation is two low. The Windows solution is called Ultramon.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang! We consider questions just asking for a list of software off topic since there's no one correct answer. This question is a little borderline, and we'd much rather have one or two canonical answers explaining how to do it instead of collecting a dozen of tools, because these kinds of questions have shown to become cluttered over time and simply polling for popularity. I rephrased your question a little to make it a better fit. I'd ask you not to post individual tools to achieve this as separate answers, but rather improve sidran32's answer for example.

Comment: It would be great to get the question reopened - there is still no answer for linux and no canoncial answer that goes over all three operating systems. The other questions is not asking for a multi or cross-operating system solution.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, you can just use the Windows key plus left or right. On multimonitor setups, hitting <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> a couple times will move the window to the next monitor. If you want to maximize the window, use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>. To then restore it, use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>. Pressing that again will minimize, and then using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> will restore it after minimizing, with <kbd>1</kbd> starting at the leftmost button on the taskbar. No need for a 3rd party utility.

You also could use keyboard shortcuts to move the window manually. This is a bit slower than the above method, however, but works with all versions of Windows. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open the window control menu, and press <kbd>M</kbd> to select "Move". Then use <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> to move the window around (you can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while using <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> to move in increments of 1 pixel). Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will drop the window when you're done.

A similar method in Linux (Gnome, I don't know about other WMs) is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to move the window, and use <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> to move the window around (again, holding  to move in increments of 1 pixel if you'd like), and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to drop the window in place.

I don't know about how to do any of this in Mac OSX, as I'm not as familiar with that OS. If someone knows a way using the keyboard, leave a comment and I can edit it in (or, edit it in yourself).