# Linux - How to set up a shortcut to move window to different monitor?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-monitors, gnome

I am using CentOS 6.4.

I am aware the similar question has been raised before for [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/490018/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-windows-around-on-multiscreen-setup) and [OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/331313/how-to-automagically-move-windows-between-monitors-with-one-keystroke), but so far, the only solution I found for Linux is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and move it pixel-by-pixel, which is really slow in a multi-monitor setting.

Is there a shortcut to move a window monitor-by-monitor?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? (Gnome, KDE, etc.)

Comment: `gnome`. Sorry forgot to say

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-[arrow key]` does not work for monitors, right? I mean, it is only for switching between workspaces, right? You might have to hack together something with xdotool.