# Shortcut to move window to other display on Windows

Tags: windows, display, keyboard-shortcuts

On Ubuntu, one can create a [keyboard shortcut to move windows between displays](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22207/quickly-place-a-window-to-another-screen-using-only-the-keyboard) (when displays are extended). [This seems possible on a Mac too](https://superuser.com/questions/331313/how-to-automagically-move-windows-between-monitors-with-one-keystroke).

How can one do this on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut is [Win + Shift + Left/Right arrow key](http://lifehacker.com/5828453/move-windows-around-quickly-using-your-keyboard-in-windows-7).